# Multi Key dictionary implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map

### Description

I had to create a dictionary structure where one value can be referenced by several keys.

For example the keys `a`, `b`, `c` reference the value 1 and `d`, `e` reference the value 2. If two groups of keys intersect then I want to merge them, for example the group `a`, `b` and `b`, `c` should result to `a`, `b`, `c`.

I also need an efficient solution:

- linear time for creation (init) - \$O(n)\$.
- constant time for access (update and get) - \$O(1)\$
- no need for inserting and delete since I have the final list of keys at the init

I'm come from Java world and I'm not totally confortable with the Python philosophy so I think some review could be useful.

### Main code

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from typing import Iterator, Set, FrozenSet, AbstractSet, ValuesView, Tuple

class MultiKeysDict(Mapping):
    """
     Dictionary to manage multiple key to one value.
     The keys groupes should be set at the initialization and can't change later.
     If two keys groupes share a key so they will reference the same value.
     """

    class Value:
        """
        Store the value data
        """

        def __init__(self, default_value):
            self.data = default_value

    def __init__(self, grp_keys: Set[FrozenSet], default_value = None):
        """
        Create a dictionary based keys groups.
        Every group will share the same value. Intersected group will share the same value.
        :param grp_keys: The groups of keys.
        :param default_value: The default value.
        """
        self._storage = dict()
        self._values = set()

        # Build all keys
        reverse_dict = dict()  # For groupe merging
        for keys in grp_keys:
            refs = set()
            for key in keys:
                if key in self._storage:
                    refs.add(self._storage[key])

            # New group of keys
            if not refs:
                new_value = MultiKeysDict.Value(default_value)
                self._storage.update(dict.fromkeys(keys, new_value))
                reverse_dict[new_value] = set(keys)
                self._values.add(new_value)

            # Extend an existing group of keys
            elif len(refs) == 1:
                old_value = refs.pop()
                self._storage.update(dict.fromkeys(keys, old_value))
                reverse_dict[old_value].update(keys)

            # Merge several group of keys (troubles start here)
            else:
                old_value = refs.pop()
                keys_to_merge = [key for ref in refs for key in reverse_dict[ref]]
                self._storage.update(dict.fromkeys(keys_to_merge, old_value))
                reverse_dict[old_value].update(keys_to_merge)
                # Remove merged references
                for ref in refs:
                    del reverse_dict[ref]
                    self._values.discard(ref)

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self._storage[k].data

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._storage[key].data = value

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._values)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator:
        return (value.data for value in self._values)

    def keys(self) -> AbstractSet:
        return self._storage.keys()

    def values(self) -> ValuesView:
        return [value.data for value in self._values] # Should be ValuesView type?

    def items(self) -> AbstractSet[Tuple]:
        return {(key, self.__getitem__(key)) for key in self.keys()}
```

### Some tests

```
import unittest

from tools.multikey_dict import MultiKeysDict


class TestMultiKeyDict(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_basic_init(self):
        # Expected: [a, b] [c, d] [e, f, g]
        d = MultiKeysDict({
            frozenset({'a', 'b'}),
            frozenset({'c', 'd'}),
            frozenset({'e', 'f', 'g'})
        })

        d['a'] = 42
        d['c'] = 'lolilol'
        d['f'] = [1, 2, 3]

        # [a, b]
        self.assertEqual(d['a'], d['b'])
        self.assertEqual(d['b'], 42)

        # [c, d]
        self.assertEqual(d['c'], d['d'])
        self.assertEqual(d['d'], 'lolilol')

        # [e, f, g]
        self.assertIs(d['e'], d['f'])
        self.assertIs(d['e'], d['g'])
        self.assertEqual(d['f'], [1, 2, 3])

    def test_intersection_init(self):
        # Expected: [a, b, c] [d, e]
        d = MultiKeysDict({
            frozenset({'a', 'b'}),
            frozenset({'b', 'c'}),
            frozenset({'d', 'e'})
        })

        d['a'] = 1
        d['d'] = 2

        # [a, b, c]
        self.assertEqual(d['b'], 1)
        self.assertEqual(d['c'], 1)
        self.assertIs(d['a'], d['c'])

        # [d, e]
        self.assertIs(d['d'], d['e'])

    def test_merge_init(self):
        # Expected: [a, b, c, d] [e, f]
        d = MultiKeysDict({
            frozenset({'a', 'b'}),
            frozenset({'c', 'd'}),
            frozenset({'b', 'c'}),
            frozenset({'e', 'f'})
        })

        d['a'] = 1

        # [a, b, c, d]
        self.assertEqual(d['a'], 1)
        self.assertEqual(d['b'], 1)
        self.assertEqual(d['c'], 1)
        self.assertEqual(d['d'], 1)
```

The code seems to work as expected but I'm not sure about my implementation, especially the `values()` and `items()` part.

Comment: Code well organised, docstring, type annotations & unit-tests. You have great habits already!

Comment: When you say you need it to run in \$O(n)\$ time what do you mean, creation, indexing, iterating, finding the length? Can one of these be faster - like indexing, and length are \$O(1)\$ in my answer. And can one be slower, creation can be \$O(n^2)\$.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I edited the question to make it clearer. I think my current code respect these criteria.

Comment: @Opsse I've re-read your `__init__` and it looks like it runs in \$O(n^2)\$ time. This is as `refs` worst case can be `grp_keys`, meaning that you have both an outer and inner loop looping over `grp_keys`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes you are right I didn't see this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `collections.abc.Mapping` is meant to be *immutable*. You want `MutableMapping`.
2. The result from `list(d)` is *unpythonic*, it's standard to return the same as `Mapping.keys`.
3. You default all values to `None`, this smells really fishy to me. This means on an empty dictionary it says it's full, it also means `d[key]` magically returns `None`. And `key in d` is always `True`.
4. Personally I'd create two dictionaries, the first would translate from known keys to the `frozenset`. The second would be the the actual dictionary with the keys as the `frozenset`.
5. It's a bit strange to me that you'd pass poorly constructed sets to `MultiKeysDict`, but it's possible to have it merge the keys provided. However this runs in \$O(n^2)\$ time. I provided this as a `classmethod`.

   If you prefer it to run on all creations then you can just change the call slightly and call it from `__init__`.

```
import collections


class MultiKeysDict(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, translations):
        self._data = {}
        self._translations = {
            k: set_
            for set_ in translations
            for k in set_
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_overlapping(cls, sets):
        handled = set()
        for set_ in sets:
            to_merge = {s for s in handled if s & set_}
            for s in to_merge:
                handled.remove(s)
                set_ |= s
            handled.add(set_)
        return cls(handled)

    def _translate(self, key):
        if key not in self._data:
            key = self._translations[key]
        return key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[self._translate(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._data[self._translate(key)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._data[self._translate(key)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
```

Comment: I will take a look about `MutableMapping` and `list(d)`. About the `None` issue I'm not sure to get it. The `in` condition will return `True` if the key is set and `False` if not, which seems to be the [standard behaviours](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) for `dict`, no ?

Comment: About the implementation you suggest, I think this doesn't fit the keys intersection case that I explained in the description (or I misunderstood something). This raise a `KeyError` in my second unit test for `self.assertEqual(d['c'], 1)`.

Comment: @Opsse `d = {}; 'a' in d is False; d['a']` results in an index error. Yours results in `'a' in d is True; d['a'] is None`. This is non-standard and frankly bizarre behavior. As for the second aspect yes, I'll fix that in a bit.

Comment: I agree that it makes more sense to move the key merging logic out of the init, I will do the same. I understand your point about the `None` default, but in my use case I need to set a default value that I will update later. So maybe I should make the default value mandatory at the init.

Comment: @Opsse You are free to ignore my advice. I've said what is standard and normal usage, if you want to divert from that, then that's up to you.

Comment: Actually I listened you advice, I suggested to remove the `None` for a mandatory default value.

Answer (score 8):

At first glance, your code looks quite good. I would like to share some of my thoughts with you nevertheless.

1. Some variable names could be improved to make the code more readable. For instance `grp_keys`, seems to hint towards keys to groups. To me it would be more intuitive if the name was something like `key_groups`, which does sound more what you actually want from the user. One can likely argue about this. The name `self._storage` is also quite generic.
2. There should be no whitespace around the `=` when used for keyword arguments, i.e. `default_value=None` instead of `default_value = None` ([relevant PEP8 section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements))
3. Some of the comments could use a second look. E.g. `groupes` should likely be `groups` and there are a few sentences that don't make much sense, e.g. `Every group will share the same value. Intersected group will share the same value.` should likely be `Every key of a group will share the same value. Intersecting groups will also share the same value.`
4. Using `Set[FrozenSet]` to initialize your class might be overly restrictive. Your code should work fine with other sequence types and likely even iterables.

---

It took me quite some time to understand what's going on in `__init__`. While thinking about an alternative solution I arrived at something similar to [@Peilonrayz'](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221745/92478). <s>so I won't duplicate that. Using this approach invalidates the last point mentioned above and you should stick with your current approach.</s> My approach can be found below. I'm not sure if it meets your complexity requirements, but it did pass your tests.

**A word of warning:** As @Peilonrayz rightfully pointed out in a comment, the presented implementation will fail for cases like `MultiKeysDict([frozenset('ab'), frozenset('cd'), frozenset('bc')])`. The changes need to fix that would lead to what he presented in his answer.

```py
class MultiKeysDict(Mapping):
    """
     Dictionary to manage multiple key to one value.
     The keys groups has to be set at initialization and can't change later.
     If two keys groups share a key they will reference the same value.
     """

    class Value:
        """
        Store the value data
        """

        def __init__(self, default_value):
            self.data = default_value

        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Value({self.data!r})"

    def __init__(self, key_groups: Set[FrozenSet], default_value=None):
        """Create a dictionary based on key groups.

        Every key in a group will share the same value.
        Intersecting groups will also share the same value.

        :param key_groups: The groups of keys.
        :param default_value: The default value.
        """
        self._proxy = dict()
        self._data = dict()

        current_group_id = 0
        for keys in key_groups:
            known_keys = keys.intersection(self._proxy.keys())
            if known_keys:  # merge
                key = next(iter(known_keys))
                self._proxy.update(dict.fromkeys(keys, self._proxy[key]))
            else:
                self._proxy.update(dict.fromkeys(keys, current_group_id))
                self._data[current_group_id] = MultiKeysDict.Value(default_value)
                current_group_id += 1

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data[self._proxy[key]].data

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._data[self._proxy[key]].data = value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)
```

Comment: I agree with most of your points, I will fix it. I can only argue about `Set[FrozenSet]`, I don't think I can make it less restrictive since `Set[Set]` is not possible (only `FrozenSet` is hashable). And other collection type would be too generic because I don't want duplicated value.

Comment: About Peilonrayz answer I think it doesn't work. I explained why in comment.

Comment: Maybe I will have another look at my approach once I get back home and add it to the answer.

Comment: @Opsse: I added my approach to the answer.

Comment: FYI `MultiKeysDict([frozenset('ab'), frozenset('cd'), frozenset('bc')])._proxy == {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 1}`. d should also be 0. (Note the input is a list to force this output)

Comment: @Peilonrayz: Good catch!

Comment: I will use your both code to improve mine, thank you for your time.